# Rails simple form does not submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a form builded using `simple_form_for` helper in rails that won't submit, when I add these two fields:

```
<%=f.input :startDate, :as => :datetime_picker%>
<%=f.input :endDate, :as => :datetime_picker%>
```

And this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
      language: 'en'
    });
    $('#actioncustom_timezone').set_timezone({format: 'city'});
    $("#actioncustom_timezone").select2({ width: "300px" });
  });
</script>
```

When I have these two fields in my form an click submit, the view does not render with failures. When I remove these two fields the form submits perfectly and even shows error.

What is so special about the date field that they break my form when I add them?

EDIT: All the form code:

```
<h1>New Custom Action</h1>

<div class="row">
<div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= simple_form_for(@actionCustom) do |f|%>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

    <%=f.label :action_name%>
    <%=f.text_field :action_name%></br>

    <%=f.label :contentURL, "Content URL"%>
    <%=f.text_field :contentURL%></br>

    <%=f.label :callBackURL, "Callback URL"%>
    <%=f.text_field :callBackURL%></br>

    <%=f.label :customcallbackURL, "Callback URL with custom conent URL"%>
    <%=f.text_field :customcallbackURL%></br>

    <%=f.label :previewImageURL, "Preview image URL"%>
    <%=f.text_field :previewImageURL%></br>

    <%=f.date_ :startDate, :as => :datetime_picker%>
    <%=f.input :endDate, :as => :datetime_picker%>

    <%=f.label :timezone, "Timezone"%>
    <%=f.time_zone_select :timezone%>

    <%=f.label :message%>
    <%=f.text_area :message%></br>

    <%=f.label :maxSend, "Max number of all sendings"%>
    <%=f.number_field :maxSend, options = {:min=>0,:value=>0}%></br>

    <%=f.label :maxSendToday, "Max number of sendings per day"%>
    <%=f.number_field :maxSendToday, options = {:min=>0,:value=>0}%></br>

    <%=f.label :maxSendDevice, "Max number of sendings per device"%>
    <%=f.number_field :maxSendDevice, options = {:min=>0,:value=>0}%></br>

    <%=f.label :maxSendDeviceToday,"Max number of sendings per device per day"%>
    <%=f.number_field :maxSendDeviceToday, options = {:min=>0,:value=>0}%></br>


    <%=f.hidden_field :clientID, :value => current_client.id%>

    <%= f.submit "Create Action", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>

    <%end%>
</div>
 </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
   $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  language: 'en'
  });
  $('#actioncustom_timezone').set_timezone({format: 'city'});
  $("#actioncustom_timezone").select2({ width: "300px" });
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you please send all the form code? is it in ajax (using remote: true) ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this gem https://github.com/zpaulovics/datetimepicker-rails ?

If you are on rails4 you can use the new **date_field** which is using new HTML5 pickers.
With this solution you don't need to use jQuery datetimepicker.

If you are not using rails4 you can just set the input type as **date** or **datetime** like

```
<input id="user_born_on" name="user[born_on]" type="datetime" />
```

and you will get a picker on HTML5 browsers.

[image]

I have created an example code for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/2NAL5/

More on this here: http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/new-html5-form-input-helpers-rails-4-countdown-to-2013

Comment: Jep I am using this gem. It worked also very good until I created my project from scratch again because of some major changes I had to make

Comment: give it a try to my solution! It's cleaner (and lighter) then use a javascript datepicker.

Comment: <%=f.datetime_field :endDate%>
I did this, but it is not working in safari nor firefox. Also removed javascript.

Comment: Is it only working in Chrome? can you please paste the html code of the rendered page in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/Z2rKH/
It does not work in chrome,ie,safari and firefox

Answer (score 0):

So I solved my problem. I found out that in the HTML code the date time input was set as required. So when the field was empty I could not submit the form. But after modifying the date time line to this:

```
        <%=f.input :startDate,:as => :datetime_picker,:required => false%>
```

It Works!!!!!